# flask-SQLAlchemy: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter_by' error when adding relations

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create the following Structure for my DB:

I have a Parent class `UserModel` with `ChefModel` and `CustomerModel` as children. Everything is working fine until I try adding relations between an `OrderModel` and both classes. I get the following error on all calls to `UserModel` or `ChefModel`. For example, when I try to find a Chef:

```
    File "C:\Users\Moham\Documents\Food order\resources\chef.py", line 60, in get
    users = ChefModel.query.filter_by(active = True).all()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter_by'
```

Here is my ChefModel:

```
class ChefModel(UserModel):
    __tablename__ = 'chefs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key = True)
    food_items = db.relationship("FoodItemModel", backref="chef", lazy=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'chefs'}
```

CustomerModel:

```
class CustomerModel(UserModel):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key = True)   
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'customers'}
```

And OrderModel:

```
class OrderModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)    
    updated_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    description = db.Column(db.String(254)) 
    food_items = db.relationship("FoodItemModel", secondary = association_table)
    customer_id = db.relationship(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customers.id')) //if remove this line
    chef_id = db.relationship(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('chefs.id')) //and this line, calls are normal
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the issue is with the filter? Try `users = ChefModel.query.filter(ChefModel.active.is_(True)).all()`

Comment: What does the `UserModel` base class look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've incorrectly specified the customer_id and chef_id columns in `OrderModel`. Try doing something like this:

```
class OrderModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    updated_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    description = db.Column(db.String(254)) 
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("customers.id"))
    chef_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("chefs.id"))
```